# Sencha Touch :: KitchenSink :: How are the controllers instantiated?

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, sencha-touch

I'm trying to understand how the kitchensink example loads itself and I'm getting stuck on the controllers.

Apparently the views come from the route inside the Main controller. But I don't understand how the controller are instantiated.

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the  app.js file,it contains below line of code

```
profiles: ['Tablet', 'Phone'],
```

Now if you see both of these profile files(Tablet.js and Phone.js),both of these contains a config property

```
controllers: ['Main'],
```

Which is responsible for instantiation of controller.

The reason why this is not placed inside app.js directly is unnecessary loading.Loading of controller is done as per device.